# IPv6 AAAA vs. CNAME for same domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I reach my home site through a DynDNS name, and also have tunneled IPv6 there.

In the DNS zone, I have:

```
myhomesite CNAME example.dyndns.org.
```

How do I simultaneously point "myhomesite" to an AAAA record? If I trivially make it

```
myhomesite CNAME example.dyndns.org.
myhomesite AAAA  2001:db8::1:2:3:4
```

the zone is invalid (CNAME and other data).

Can you suggest a way for having the CNAME record and the AAAA record visible behind the same domain name?

What I'm not looking for is an ".ipv6."-infixed record, which already is in place.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I copy from DNS for [Rocket Scientists](http://zytrax.com/books/dns/):

> CNAME RRs cannot have any other RRs
>   with the same name, for example, a TXT
>   - well that was true until DNSSEC came along and in this case RRSIG, NSEC and
>   certain KEY RRs can now occupy the
>   same name.

Therefore what you want to do cannot be done using a CNAME.  Use the CNAME to access your homesite via IPv4 and have a myhomesite-v6 AAAA record point to the IPv6 address

If you do not want such a solution, you have to implement a mechanism that updates your DNS zone each time your IP address changes with:

```
myhomesite IN A IPv4.add.ress
           IN AAAA IPv6.add.ress
```

But that depends on the API (if any) that your DNS provider exports to you.  For example if I had root access on the DNS server, I would periodically `host -t a example.dyndns.org` and use the output to update the zonefile with the IPv4 address for myhomesite.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The alternative that I have now is a BIND dynamic zone with a permanent AAAA record that accompanies the dynamic A record. It's not particularly hard to understand that CNAME and AAAA for the same domain can't coexist, but still, maybe there's a clever workaround that allows the use of DynDNS.

Comment: There is no workaround to the "`CNAME` rides alone" problem.